# What is the difference between Nano 328p-au and 328p-mu?

Tags: arduino-nano

What is the difference between Nano 328p-au and 328p-mu? Does it have to do with the updated bootloader or is it just a different board design? I want to make sure I order the correct one and I could not find a proper answer so far. Thanks.

Comment: The only difference is the MCU package. If you're ordering the pre-assembled Nano boards, it makes no practical difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AU and MU on the chip just refer to the shape of the chip. AU is TQFP and MU is VQFN.

You can see the full list of suffixes [here](https://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/en/ATmega328p) (select the red "Buy Now" tab for a table).